# Grapefruit seedling

Tags: houseplants, seedlings, citrus

I'm new to citrus and I started germinating and then planting these grapefruits 3 months ago. Is this normal progress? I also have watered them every 2-3 days. Just asking for any tips on how to get them to grow better / prevent any pests or diseases.[grapefruit seedlings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z2f5.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Try to post pictures and ask specific questions so they can be answered accurately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grapefruit are very slow growing. They need a LOT of sunlight, and don’t let the soil dry out completely. Fish emulsion is a good fertilizer.

My grapefruit from seed are now probably 4 or 5 years old and they’re only 2 to 3 ft tall. One finally started growing big mature leaves for the first time this year.

Update: it occurs to me I should have mentioned I live in Connecticut, so my trees have fewer sun and fewer heat hours than trees grown in Florida, and the Southwest. This certainly contributes to the slower growth my trees experience.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip. I live in Texas and my plants are on a windowsill with lots of sunlight. I water them every few days, but is it ok to only water the center of the plant? Or do I water the whole pot? I was watering more frequently earlier but they attracted fungus gnats, which were hard to get rid of. Also I used a bit of superthrive fertilizer. I don't know if that is a fish fertilizer or not.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer, they are slow, like avocados. I lost track of how old my plants are, at least 3 years old, and they are about 3 1/2 foot shrubs. Mine are in-ground and I water them only in the dry season just at roots.  I don’t fertilize much, just once a season, and I use a citrus fertilizer for those, and save my fishy stuff for my bananas. I’m in central Florida so they get lots of sun and water.